# How to add a default value for update in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a boolean column where I have added a default value of false. It is my understanding that the default value will kick in when I add new rows to the table. However, I would like a default value of false when the rows are updated as well. Is that possible?

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn SET DEFAULT false;

-- In below query the mycolumn should default to false 
update mytable set somecolumn = 'somevalue' 
where somecolumn = 'anothervalue'

-- In below query mycolumn should be true since the value is specified
update mytable set somecolumn = 'somevalue' mycolumn = true 
where somecolumn = 'anothervalue'
```

Comment: Would you allow to explicitly set it to `NULL` in an `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a trigger as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mytriggerfunction()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS '                                        
BEGIN
  IF NEW.mycolumn IS NULL OR NEW.mycolumn='''' THEN
    NEW.mycolumn := ''somedefaultvalue'';
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mytriggerfunction();
```

Comment: @Anthony does this help?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. But only if you add a trigger. There is no special clause in the `create table` statement to do this.

Comment: How would I add a trigger to accomplish this?

Comment: @Anthony: a trigger knows the old value and the new value for every column. If old.col=true and new.col=true you don't know wether `SET col=true` was in the UPDATE. If you care about that case, the trigger is not your solution.